# for loop not working correctly with json encode Php

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to fetch members ratings from the database using ajax. I passed a function to the JSON, even though it returned a value in the function but it doesn't execute the for loop condition.

Here is my code, the loop failed to execute. What am I doing wrong?

```
    function mrate($irate) {
        $class = "fa-star star-filled";
        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            if ($irate <= $i) {
                $class = "fa-star-o empty";
            }
            return '<i class="fa ' . $class . '"></i>';
        }
    }

    $perPage = 2;
    if (isset($_GET["page"]) && isset($_GET["page"])) {
        $page = $_GET["page"];
        $pid = $mysqli->real_string_escape($_GET["pid"]);
    } else {
        $page = 1;
        $pid = $mysqli->real_string_escape($_SESSION['pid']);
    };

    $startFrom = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT id, name,
        review, rating, added_date
        FROM review_rating
        where product_id = '$pid'
        ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $startFrom, $perPage";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlQuery);
    $paginationHtml = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $img = '<img class="rounded-circle" width="50" src="' . $set['installUrl'] . 'assets/img/login.png" alt="' . $row["name"] . '"/>';
        $irate = $row['rating'];

        $paginationHtml .= '<div  class="product-review pb-4 mb-4 border-bottom">';
        $paginationHtml .= '<div class="d-flex mb-3">';
        $paginationHtml .= '<div class="media media-ie-fix align-items-center mr-4 pr-2">' . $img;
        $paginationHtml .= '<div class="media-body pl-3"><h6 class="font-size-sm mb-0">' . $row["name"] . '</h6>';
        $paginationHtml .= '<span class="font-size-ms text-muted">' . $row['added_date'] . '</span></div></div>';
        $paginationHtml .= '<div><div class="star-rating">' . mrate($irate) . '</div></div>';
        $paginationHtml .= '</div>';
        $paginationHtml .= '<p class="font-size-md mb-2">' . $row['review'] . '</p>';
        $paginationHtml .= '</div>';
    }
    $jsonData = array(
        "html" => $paginationHtml,
    );
    echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

Comment: Your `for` loop won't iterate more than once because of the `return` statement.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, how could I return the value in the function without using  retun?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do in `mrate` function, especially in *that* `for` loop?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, I am trying to print out the number of rating per members. The star-icon appears 5 times. Out of the 5 stars, get number of rating per member which brings out the looping.

Comment: I have given an answer below to address your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `function mrate($irate)` with this and try. You needed to concatenate the stars code to display it more than once.

```
function mrate($irate){
    $stars = '';
    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
        if($irate <= $i){
            $class = "fa-star-o empty";
        }else{
            $class = "fa-star star-filled";
        }
        $stars .= '<i class="fa '.$class.'"></i>';
    }
    return $stars;
}
```

Comment: You could factor out the `$stars .= ...` part so that you don't repeat it in both branches of the `if..else...`

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you for the reminder, edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who contributed. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's no fractional rating, you can do the following - Display all 5 stars but solid ones will represent the rating.

```
function mrate($irate){
    $class = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
        if ($irate <= $i) {
            $class .= '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
        } else {
            $class .= '<i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>';
        }
    }
    return $class;
}
```